# Laravel AJAX can't get response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm working with the Laravel framework and I'm making an AJAX request to send an email. The request works fine and the mail is sent, the problem is I can't get the server response if the mail has been sent successfully or not.

Here's the code (short version) wich is located under views/contact/mail.blade.php :

```
if( mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers) )  {
    $data = array( 'text' => Lang::line('contact.mail-success')->get() );
    return Response::json($data);
} else {
    $data = array( 'text' => Lang::line('contact.mail-error')->get() );
    return Response::json($data);
}
```

and here's the jquery :

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: BASE+'/contact',
            type: 'post',
            data: { name: $('#name').val(), mail: $('#email').val(), message: $('#msg').val() },
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
               var message = $.parseJSON(data);
               alert(message.text); // here I get the "cannot read property of null" in the console log
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the raw response of your ajax call in the console? Can you check that? I think putting a "return" statement inside a blade view is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Using console.log(data), I get a "null" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel sends the correct headers with Response::json there's no need to parse the JSON in your Javascript, simply change the line

```
var message = $.parseJSON(data);
```

to

```
var message = data;
```

Comment: Posted under a new account, oops. Silly SO.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, but it still isn't working. Could it have something to do with the routing? Looking at the "JSON Responses" section on [codehappy.daylerees.com](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/ajax-content), I don't have anywhere the code that is there.

Comment: Could you console.log(data) (without any kind of parsing or anything)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `return Response::json()` from a view file, the view are supposed to echo whatever output generated from the view but in this case you need to return the response from the route itself, as json would also include header information.

Comment: Oh jeeze, I had no idea he said view file, I thought this was being done from the controller.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't specify it clearly. Now, I made a controller with the same code as my view under controllers/contact.php and a route with the following code : `Route::post('/contact', array('as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'contact@ajax_mail'));` and now I get a "POST http://www.mysite.com/mysite/public/fr/contact 404 (Not Found)" error in the console

Comment: Could you clarify whether this is Laravel 3 or Laravel 4? I guessing Laravel 3 but just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

While sending a response in form of JSON must be encoded using `json_encode();` in PHP. after successful reach of done method then parse the object as `JSON.parse();`

Example :

Modify the line in php file as
`return response()->json(json_encode($data));`

add the line in javascript files as

```
done(function (data){
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
console.log(data.text);
});
```